# arguments to python script from R

Tags: python, r

I have to pass some values to a python script and get some values back from it in R. I am presently using rPython library in R. I am able to get values from script using `python.get(var_name)`. How can I send values to python script? 
Anything other than rPython which can help me do this is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python.assign seems to be the function you need.

From the [package documentation](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/rPython/rPython.pdf) for RPython:

```
Description
    Functions that assign and get Python variables from R.
Usage
    python.assign(var.name, value, ...)
    python.get(var.name)

Arguments
    var.name   a character string containing a valid python variable name
    value      an R object whose equivalent wants to be assigned to the variable in python
    ...        other arguments passed to the internal toJSON function cal
```